# Ubuntu 8.04 NIC change

Tags: ubuntu, network-adapter

I had a small box running ubntu 8.04 on it and it broke down. I moved the hard drive from it to a new box running different hardware just to see if i might be lucky and get a quick fix with no need to reinstall everything. the system boots up nicely, only problem i found is that ubuntu does not recognize the NIC on this new box. Is there any way i can manually fix this so i am not forced to reinstall?

P.S. New box is an Asus EEE 1000H

Things i've tried so far:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Failed to bring up eth0.

lshw
  *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet Controller
    product: Attansic Technology Corp.
    vendor: Attansic Technology Corp.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    version: b0
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0

commenting/deleting /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Comment: The most likely scenario is the kernel shipped with 8.04 does not have drivers for the Attansic nics.  Your options would be to use a temporary external USB based nic or download and build the kernel module for the Attansic nic.